# Error?? texmaker's build-in viewer

Tags: graphics, texmaker, eps, viewers, epslatex

I made a eps file from gnuplot.
But, texmaker's build-in viewer can't view it correctly.Other viewer works.
The problem is that the Greek letters change to a diifferent letter.And some other letter's too.
example: mu to "propotion", pi to "unequal".
alpha, beta and chi are viewed correctly.

What is wrong???

gnuplot code

```
set terminal postscript enhanced 'Helvetica, 50'
set output "picture.eps"
plot x title "{/Symbol abcmp\325\326\327}"
```

tex code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[dvipdfmx]{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=10cm]{picture.eps}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

They are viewing the same PDF file made from Texmaker.

Texmaker's build-in viewer
[image: Texmaker's build-in viewer]

Adobe Reader
[image: Adobe Reader]

Thanks for answering my question, but it doesn't work.I tried this.

```
set terminal postscript eps enhanced color 'Times, 30'
set output 'picture.eps'
plot x title "$\\alpha \\beta \\chi \\mu \\pi \\prod \\sqrt$",\
-x title '$\\alpha \\beta \\chi \\mu \\pi \\prod \\sqrt$',\
x/2 title "$\alpha \beta \chi \mu \pi \prod \sqrt$",\
-x/2 title '$\alpha \beta \chi \mu \pi \prod \sqrt$'
```

[image]

The Texmaker is `Texmaker4.1.1`.
I "was" using `latex(platex)` and `dvipdfm(dvipdfmx)`.

`latex -version`

> pdfTeX 3.1415926-1.40.11+tagged-pdf-2.2 (Web2C 2010)
>   kpathsea version 6.0.0
>   Copyright 2010 Peter Breitenlohner (eTeX)/Han The Thanh (pdfTeX).
>   There is NO warranty.
>   Redistribution of this software is covered by the terms of both the pdfTeX copyright and
>   the Lesser GNU General Public License.
>   For more information about these matters, see the file
>   named COPYING and the pdfTeX source.
>   Primary author of pdfTeX: Peter Breitenlohner (eTeX)/Han The Thanh (pdfTeX).
>   Compiled with libpng 1.4.4; using libpng 1.4.4
>   Compiled with zlib 1.2.5; using zlib 1.2.5
>   Compiled with xpdf version 3.02pl5

`platex -version`

> pdfTeX 3.1415926-1.40.11+tagged-pdf-2.2 (Web2C 2010)
>   kpathsea version 6.0.0
>   Copyright 2010 Peter Breitenlohner (eTeX)/Han The Thanh (pdfTeX).
>   There is NO warranty.
>   Redistribution of this software is covered by the terms of both the pdfTeX copyright and the Lesser GNU General Public License.
>   For more information about these matters, see the file named COPYING and the pdfTeX source.
>   Primary author of pdfTeX: Peter Breitenlohner (eTeX)/Han The Thanh (pdfTeX).
>   Compiled with libpng 1.4.4; using libpng 1.4.4
>   Compiled with zlib 1.2.5; using zlib 1.2.5
>   Compiled with xpdf version 3.02pl5

`dvipdfmx --help`

> This is dvipdfmx-20120420 by the DVIPDFMx project team,
>   modified for TeX Live,
>   an extended version of dvipdfm-0.13.2c developed by Mark A. Wicks.

I installed new `latex(platex)` and `dvipdfmx`, but it doesn't work neither.

`platex -version`

> e-pTeX 3.14159265-p3.5-130605-2.6 (sjis) (TeX Live 2014/W32TeX)
>   kpathsea version 6.2.0
>   ptexenc version 1.3.2
>   Copyright 2014 D.E. Knuth.
>   There is NO warranty.
>   Redistribution of this software is covered by the terms of both the e-pTeX copyright and
>   the Lesser GNU General Public License.
>   For more information about these matters, see the file
>   named COPYING and the e-pTeX source.
>   Primary author of e-pTeX: Peter Breitenlohner.

`dvipdfmx --version`

> This is dvipdfmx Version 20140317 by the DVIPDFMx project team,
>   modified for TeX Live,
>   an extended version of dvipdfm-0.13.2c developed by Mark A. Wicks.

I tried hard, and finally I did it! Thanakyou. but there are few problems.  see below.
gnuplot code

```
set terminal epslatex size 9cm,7cm  
set output 'picture_test.tex'  
set xlabel '$x$'  
set ylabel '$\left(\frac{\mu\sin(x)}{x}\right)^{2\alpha}$'  
set xrange [-10:10]  
set yrange [-10:10]  
plot x title "abc$\\alpha \\beta \\chi \\mu \\pi \\prod \\sqrt{123}$",-x  
set output  
set terminal wxt
```

tex code

```
>\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage{graphicx}  
\usepackage{epstopdf}  
\begin{document}  
\begin{figure}[htbp]  
\centering  
\input{picture_test}  
\caption{graph$graph$}  
\end{figure}  
\end{document}
```

Texmaker User Quick Build Command

```
platex -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex|dvips %.dvi|ps2eps -f %.ps|epstopdf %.eps
```

Warnings

```
....Package epstopdf Warning: Drivers other than `pdftex.def' are not supported....
```

I removed the texcode `\usepackage{epstopdf}`, then it dissapeared.

Texmaker Build-in Viewer
[image]

the problem's is that the picture size is too big? it doesn't fit in to the page.
I have a another question, how can I call build-in viewer from the User Quick Build command?

Nevermind these questions. I got it.
I changed  tex code to`\usepackage[dvipdfmx]{graphicx}`and the command to `latex`(platex)and`dvipdfmx`. It works!
[image]

Comment: thanks for answering, but it doesn't work. I uploaded the picture.

Comment: Your original setup worked for me, also in TeXMaker. Which version/distribution of TeX and TeXMaker do you use?

Comment: It looks like you've got two separate accounts, which means you cannot edit your original post or leave comments. The StackExchange staff can [merge them together for you](http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

o.k. Sorry for 1st response I assumed you know better gnuplot. The full way is this, open gnuplot and do this:

```
set terminal epslatex
set output 'plot.tex'
set xrange [-10:10]
set yrange [-10:10]
plot x title "$\\alpha \\beta \\mu \\sqrt$"
set output 'aux.tex'
```

then on your Latex doc add the pack eps2pdf, then look for the plot.tex and plot.eps files generated by gnuplot an copy them to the directory where your latex file is, after that add this on your latex file:

```
preamble
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
.
.
.
\begin{document}
\input{plot.tex}
\end{document}
```

the you get this: [image]

Comment: Doing this way you get 2 files a .eps file that contains only the plot and frame box and a .tex file that generates the ticks marks, titles, annotations and legends via Latex code compilation inside your master doc

Comment: Thanks.I failed many times, but finally it seems I done it! I'll will upload the picture.

Comment: Thank you Jared Lo! I couldn't be able to done it without your help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're using helvetica font symbols to generate the greek letters, Texmaker  viewer cannot read embedded fonts Acrobat does. try to create the same plot in gnuplot but inserting LaTex/Tex code directly i know gnuplot can

`title "$\\alpha \\beta \\chi \\mu \\pi \\prod \\sqrt$"`

Comment: As far as I know, this requires the `pslatex` terminal of gnuplot.

Comment: oops I deleted my commment sorry.  It seems that I have to study about `epslatex`